# Why won't this here-doc bash statement execute in a switch case

Tags: bash, switch-statement, heredoc

I am developing a bootstrapping script for Raspberry Pis. This script figures out if the Pi itself is a **Model 2** or **Model 3** and sets its WiFi characteristics accordingly.

The change in the WiFi characteristics is put in the `/etc/rc.local` file (**Raspbian**) and this is done through a `bootstrap.sh` script.

### Snippet

```
# model revision number to determine pi
PI_MODEL=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "Revision" | awk '{print $3}')

case "$PI_MODEL" in

"rev_1A" | "rev_1B")
    # Write the wlan config to the rc.local file
    cp /etc/rc.local /etc/rc.local.backup

    (
    cat << 'EOF'
    #!/bin/sh -e

    iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid pi-adhoc channel 6 txpower 0

    exit 0

    EOF
    ) > /etc/rc.local

    # Case for Pi-2 ends
    ;;


"pi3_rev1a" | "pi3_rev1b")

     # write the wlan config to rc.local file


     (
     cat << 'EOF'
     #!/bin/sh -e

     ifconfig wlan0 down 
     iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc channel 6 essid pi-adhoc txpower 0
     ifconfig wlan0 up

     exit 0
     EOF
     ) > /etc/rc.local
     ;;
     # case for Pi ends here
 esac
```

However in any case there is a warning issued:

> warning: here-document at line .. delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
>
> syntax error: unexpected end of file

What is possibly going wrong here?

The main idea is to check if the type of Pi and just add the respective `iwconfig` statements to `/etc/rc.local` file so that it joins a network on reboot.

#### Notes:

- in real case, this is just a snippet of a larger bootstrapping script not shown here for brevity
- the `rev_1A` etc. are not written for brevity reasons

#### References:

[Example 19-8 from tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Comment: that should not be of worry. that thing works. do you have a hint in the here-doc error and warning I get/?

Comment: Remove the quotes from `'EOF'`?

Comment: @SiKing tried both ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your here doc is indented, you should use the `-` form, so that leading tabs are removed.  You must also have the ending token at column 0, *unless you use tabs for indentation*:

```
    cat <<-'EOF'
    #!/bin/sh -e

    iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid pi-adhoc channel 6 txpower 0

    exit 0
EOF
```

from [GNU Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents)

> If the redirection operator is ‘<<-’, then all leading tab characters
>   are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter. This
>   allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural
>   fashion.

Comment: This looks like it. Can you please edit `<<-` as together that seems to work not `<< -`

Comment: Done.  The space is now removed.

Answer (score 0):

To address the "syntax error: unexpected end of file":

Instead of:

```
(
cat << 'EOF'

#code

EOF
) > /etc/rc.local
```

You want:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/rc.local

#code

EOF
```

If you want to indent you code (to make it look pretty, or whatever) **including** the `EOF` statement, you must add a `-` to ignore leading tabs, like so:

```
cat <<- EOF > /etc/rc.local

    #code

    EOF
```

Comment: This was exactly what I implemented before hand but this was also creating the same error.

Comment: And in my case as @Greg Tarsa mentioned `<<-` proves to be vital. I guess it because of the indentation

Comment: @Shan-Desai I do not understand. The `-` is only about *formatting*, it has nothing to do with *syntax*. Your post asks about syntax error.

Comment: I will try reproduce the condtions again and get back to you soon with this.

Comment: @Shan-Desai Just checked: I am wrong! I does affect syntax as well: there is a difference between `EOF` and `<tab>EOF`. The `-` will ignore the leading `<tab>`. I updated my answer. +1 to @Greg_Tarsa